# Why does Python allow importing from a local module, but not importing the module itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to understand local file imports in Python - I see lots of discussion on the topic, but can't find the specific problem I'm having.

Take the following (model) module structure:

```
project_root
  project
    load_data.py
    analyse_data.py
  tests
    test_1.py
    test_2.py
```

In test_1.py, I can import load_data perfectly using

```
from project import load_data
...
load_data.function()
```

However, if I attempt to load and access the package directly, using

```
import project as proj
...
proj.load_data.function()
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'project' has no attribute 'load_data'
```

This is true both if I run the module's test file directly (`python -m tests.test_1`), and if I run it through pytest (`python -m pytest`) in the project's root folder. Why can Python find the project when I import its components, but not when I import the package itself?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need an `__init__.py` file

Comment: In any case where `from project import load_data` works, `import project as proj` should not raise a `ModuleNotFoundError`. You might get an error on `proj.load_data.function()`, but not on `import project as proj`, and the error on `proj.load_data.function()` would be an `AttributeError`. I think you've mixed up what versions of your code gave what error messages.

Comment: @chc thanks for your reply! Unfortunately adding one doesn't remove the error, though I've been trying to avoid using them since in principle they haven't been required since Python 3.3.

Comment: @user2357112 ah apologies, you're correct, I was reading the wrong terminal output - I've updated my post.

Comment: Good, things seem to be as expected. In that case, you're running into this problem because importing a package doesn't automatically load submodules. You should load the submodule explicitly, with either `from project import load_data` or `import project.load_data`.

Comment: aaah I see, I didn't realise that submodules aren't automatically made available in Python. Thanks for your help!